# It appears there might be a bug in the rendering of the election pages

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, election

For example the "Nominations close in 6 days" line overlaps with part of the lines above:

[image]

And the same problem is on this page too:

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04, but with the same settings I've seen many election pages in the past and never saw this type of overlap, so perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: I get the same on Firefox/Windows.

Comment: This has been fixed

Comment: From a person who's released software: if you're running Ubuntu 16.04 in 2021 to *surf* (and not in, say a production server with a non-changing software, or in a VM to run some legacy proprietary software that doesn't work with modern operating systems), then *you're doing something wrong, and should update to a more recent version of Ubuntu ASAP*. Not reliably getting security updates with a high probability is not an issue of comfort in this time and age, and honestly, you're just hurting yourself with a software platform that's 5 years obsolete. (Oh, has Ubunt16.04 been bad to begin with.)

Comment: @Marcus what risk is there?

Comment: well, your software doesn't get regular updates anymore, which means most of the currently [1132 known vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4781/product_id-20550/version_id-194088/Canonical-Ubuntu-Linux-16.04.html) in Ubuntu 16.04's default configuration will never be fixed.